# Ruby enumerator with chaining

Tags: ruby

I am a newbie of Ruby and I don't quite understand the following code.

```
n = [1,2,3]
n.map!.select{|x| x+=1}
puts n.inspect
```

will give me

```
[nil, nil, nil]
```

I know that n.map! will give me an enumerator but I don't get it why calling select on it will make n becomes nil. I know that map! will modify the original object, I just don't understand how that's achieved.

**Update:**

I tried `n.map!.select {|x| true}`, n is still `[nil, nil, nil]`

I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: It's to do with the in-place modification of `map!`.

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. I tried the following code: `n = [[1],[2]]` 
`m = [[1],[2]]`

`m.map!.select {|x|}`

`n.map! do |x|
  x.select do |x|
  end
end`

`puts m.inspect`
`puts n.inspect`   and m is `[nil, nil]` and n is `[ [ ],[ ] ]` Sorry about the format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the `select` method is used for selection. It returns the element that **satisfies** the condition you placed in your block. In your case, you didn't put any condition so it returned `nil`

e.g.
You want to do something like this:

```
n = [1,2,3]
n.select { |num| num < 3 }  

#=> This should return
#=> [1,2]
```

Comment: I had the same idea as yours until I tried the following code. `a = n.select {|x| x+=1 }` and a is `[1,2,3]`. Also I tried this `a = if true e = e + 1 end`. a is 2 if e is 1.

Comment: I probably misunderstand something. Since Ruby returns its last line of code if no `return` is specified. I thought that in my example, `x += 1` is evaluated and `x` is returned. Since x is not `false` or `nil`, then we get `true` condition which makes the `a` to be `[1,2,3]`

Comment: I even tried `n.map!.select {|x| true}`, `n` is still `[nil, nil, nil]`

Comment: Is there anybody who can help to explain ? Thank you!

Comment: When Finks says "satisfies the condition" he means that the element with value `num` is selected if the expression in the block evaluates to `true`. Recall that if an expression equals to `false` or `nil`, it is logically `false`, if it equals anything else, it is logically `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, it says:

> It's to do with the in-place modification of map!

that's true. Let me make it clearer here:

In the definition of `Array#map!`, it says:

> ```
> map! {|item| block } → ary click to toggle source
> map! → Enumerator
> ```
>
> Invokes the given block once for each element of self, replacing the element with the value returned by the block

So:

#### Example 1

`[58] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[60] pry(main)> e = a.map!
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
[61] pry(main)> e.each {|n| n + 1}
=> [2, 3, 4]
[62] pry(main)> a
=> [2, 3, 4]`

However:

#### Example 2

`[71] pry(main)> a = [1,2,3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
[72] pry(main)> e = a.map!
=> #<Enumerator: ...>
[73] pry(main)> e.next
=> 1
[74] pry(main)> a
=> [1, 2, 3]
[75] pry(main)> e.peek
=> 2
[76] pry(main)> a
=> [nil, 2, 3]`

I think this due to `Enumerator#each` call takes a block, and that would be the return value from example 1; but when `Enumerator#next` is called (same goes to `Enumerator.to_a`), it cannot evaluate the block, therefore, returning `nil`.